# Sort words by frequency into hash table using qsort in C

Tags: c, quicksort, qsort

My task is to improve the runtime of a program that sorts all words from a .txt file into a hash table. This triple-nested for loop sorting algorithm is the problem:

```
// Sort hash table elements and save as pointers in 'array'
for (i = 0; i < tsize; i++)
   for (ele = htable[i]; ele != NULL; ele = ele->next) {
    if (ele->freq == 1)
    scnt++;

    for (j = cnt; j > 0 && ele->freq > array[j-1]->freq; j--)
      array[j] = array[j-1];

    array[j] = ele;
    cnt++;
}
```

What I would like to do is use qsort(), but I am lost as to where I should begin. Any suggestions will help, thank you.

UPDATE:
I have altered the above snippet as follows:

```
// Sort hash table elements and save as pointers in 'array'
for (i = 0; i < tsize; i++)
   for (ele = htable[i]; ele != NULL; ele = ele->next) {
    if (ele->freq == 1)
    scnt++;

    array[cnt] = ele;
    qsort(array, tsize, sizeof(h_ptr), (int (*) (const void *, const void *))compare_ele);
    cnt++;
}
```

and added this comparison function:

```
// Compare function for qsort
int compare_ele (h_ptr *a, h_ptr *b)
{
    if (a->freq < b->freq)
        return + 1;
    if (a->freq > b->freq)
        return - 1;
    return 0;
}
```

the structure for h_ptr is:

```
typedef struct HELE {
    char *word;
    int freq;
    struct HELE *next;
} h_rec, *h_ptr;
```

When I compile, I receive this error:

```
analysis.c: In function ‘compare_ele’:
analysis.c:137:10: error: request for member ‘freq’ in something not a structure or union
 if (a->freq < b->freq)
      ^
analysis.c:137:20: error: request for member ‘freq’ in something not a structure or union
 if (a->freq < b->freq)
                ^
analysis.c:139:10: error: request for member ‘freq’ in something not a structure or union
 if (a->freq > b->freq)
      ^
analysis.c:139:20: error: request for member ‘freq’ in something not a structure or union
 if (a->freq > b->freq)
```

Comment: Begin by reading documentation. If all else fails, the [universal source of knowledge](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qsort) is always at your disposal.

Comment: 1. [**Read** the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) 2. **Write** your callback comparator. 3. **Test** your callback comparator. 4. **Use** `qsort`. An example of usage is in the [link provided](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort).

Comment: The innermost `for` loop is doing an insertion sort, which is fairly slow, as you already found out. So remove those two lines, and replace `array[j] = ele;` with `array[cnt] = ele;` That will give you the unsorted array that you can use with `qsort`.

Comment: Thank you for the links and suggestions

Comment: @user3386109: Thank you for the helpful tip. I am confused however as to what I would do for the comparison operator as the fourth parameter in qsort.

Comment: Contradiction in your title: if you *use* `qsort` you are *not implementing* a sort, just doing one. *Implementing a sort* would mean to recode your own `qsort` like routine.

Comment: The compare function takes pointers to the items in the array. The items in the array are pointers to h_recs (i.e., h_ptrs), so the arguments to the compare function are pointers to pointers to h_recs (i.e., pointers to h_ptrs), but you're using them as if they were pointers to h_recs (i.e., h_ptrs). Also, the types of the arguments to your compare function are wrong ... you must use the documented prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two `for` loops in the updated code are creating an unsorted array, while keeping track of the number of items in the array in the variable `cnt`.  You should call `qsort` after those `for` loops are finished, and pass `cnt` as the second argument to `qsort`.

The comparison function should always follow the function prototype specified by `qsort`. It is bad practice to define a comparator function that requires a cast when used as the fourth argument to `qsort`. See the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qsort) for an example of how to write a proper comparator function.

In your case, the first two lines of the comparator function should be

```
h_rec *a = *(const h_rec **)p;
h_rec *b = *(const h_rec **)q;
```

Note that I always avoid putting `*`s in typedefs. That is the source of your error messages, you haven't properly accounted for the fact that in your code, `a` and `b` are in fact of type pointer-to-pointer-to-struct-HELE.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has helped me leaps and bounds. I have made correct usage of qsort and the program now executes in 0.2 seconds vs. 9.5 seconds from earlier.